# How to import Facebook JavaScript SDK without script tag into Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using ngx-facebook module to integrate Facebook login and it requires Facebook JavaScript SDK.
I want to download it somehow with npm, but can't find working package.
I don't like the idea of script tag which provided by facebook.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any other way which they support unfortunately. There's npm packages for server-side logic, but none for the client side. This is a common pattern with the SDKs provided by bigger companies (for Maps or ads from Google for example). You can only import them via a `<script>` and only refer to the latest version.

You could always just download the .js and place it next to your project as a "binary"-ish dependency and configure Webpack or whatever it is you're using for bundling to handle it.